# Ruby on Rails - How can I delete a single ProductItem in my Cart without deleting the whole Cart items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce

**Summary of process**

I am trying to develop a simple e-commerce app. I created **Products** which turn into **Product-Items**, These Product Items are then added to a **Cart** and then to an **Order**.

**Problem**

Everything works perfectly If I want to delete ALL ProductItems in my cart, with this code:

```
      <%= link_to 'Empty Your Cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'You sure?'} %>
```

But I cant seem to figure out how to delete ONE single item without deleting all of them.

I tried using this function

```
      <%= link_to 'Delete', @product_item, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'You sure?'} %>
```

on my Cart form:

```
<% @cart.product_items.each do|item| %>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <%= item.quantity %>&times;<%= item.product.title %> =
         <%= number_to_currency item.total_price %> - <%=item.product.size %>.

         <%= link_to 'Delete', @product_items, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'You sure?'} %>

        </li>
       </ul>

  <% end %>
```

and changing my controller many times, but nothing seems to work. I am sure its probably really simple but I am new to Rails and cant seem to figure it out.

My carts controller

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

def new
 @cart = Cart.new
end

def show
end


def destroy
 @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
 session[:cart_id] = nil
 redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your cart is empty'
end

private

def set_cart
 @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end

def cart_params
 params[:cart]
end

def invalid_cart
 logger_error = 'You are trying to access an invalid cart'
 redirect_to product_url,  notice:'Invalid Cart'
end

end
```

My cart.rb model

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord

 has_many :product_items, dependent: :destroy

 def add_product(product_id)
  current_item = product_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)

  if current_item
   current_item.quantity += 1

  else
   current_item = product_items.build(product_id: product_id)
  end
   current_item
 end

def total_price
 product_items.to_a.sum{|item| item.total_price}
end

end
```

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary code in your question (`CartsController`, `ProductsController`, `Cart`, irrelevant actions on the `ProductItemsController`, code that is not pertinent to the question) and should probably delete it so that it's easier to understand what you're getting at. Also, instead of saying "nothing seems to work", describe the incorrect behavior (Are you getting errors? Are the wrong objects getting deleted?). And, it's often helpful if you include the console output so that we can see what's happening during the transaction.

Comment: In you delete call you passing all the products, try top pass single item which is looped . try: <%= link_to 'Delete', item, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'You sure?'} %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were close, but you should've changed the destroy route to the specific item.  So change `@product_items` to the specific item `item` which is the object inside the loop.

```
<% @cart.product_items.each do|item| %>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <%= item.quantity %>&times;<%= item.product.title %> =
     <%= number_to_currency item.total_price %> - <%=item.product.size %>.

     <%= link_to 'Delete', item, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'You sure?'} %>

    </li>
   </ul>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to edit my controllers a bit, but its working now!!